# Multiple level relationships on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I have this problem. In Laravel, I have 3 Models, ie:

```
class Department{
    public function coordinations(){
        return $this->has_many('Coordination');
    }
}

class Coordination{
    public function sites(){
        return $this->has_many('Site');
    }
}

class Site{
    public function assets(){
        return $this->has_many('FAssets');
    }
}

class FAsset{}
```

I want to display all the asset grouped by Departments. I tryied to do something like:

```
@foreach($dependencias as $dep)
    <tr>
         <td colspan="8" style="width:100%">Dependencia: {{ $dep->code }} {{ $dep->description }}</td>
    </tr>
@foreach($dep->coordinations()->sites()->assets()->get() as $asset)
...
```

But I got the "Method [sites] is not defined on the Query class" error. I was looking for the eager loading way but I dont see how it could work with an extra level on the relationships.

Also, I was considering to querying all the assets and filtering the assets given the actual coordination, but I think that this is going to take a lot of time to load...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Deparment{
public function department_assets(){
    $assets = array();

    foreach($this->has_many('Coordination')->get() as $coordination){
            foreach($coordination->sites()->get() as $site){
                foreach($site->assets() as $asset)
                {
                    $assets[] = $asset;
                }
            }
        }

    return $assets;
    }
}
```

Now we can...

```
@foreach($dep->department_assets() as $asset)
```

Comment: Well, now its "Call to a member function sites() on a non-object" error, that's when theres a null value isn't?

Comment: It seems strange to me. It would help to see the context it is being used in so I can get a better understanding of what you're trying to do. It seems that it is returning an **array of objects** rather than a string, which means you're getting multiple models. Is it perhaps your **has_many** relationship is returning multiple results? As you can't do relational queries on multiple results, only usually on a **has_one** relationship. Did you try replacing all of those **get()** methods with **first()** methods?

Comment: Well, as I understand, the has many will return multiple items of the related object model. A department has associated many coordinations, a coordination has associated one or multiple sites and on a site can be one or multiple asets or items. I want to display all the assets placed on the differents sites of all the differents coordinations of every departments.

Comment: I could query the assets, but I think that the direct way to group the assets by the Department is with this approach

Comment: I see now, it seems I misunderstood what you were trying to do. Since you can only query one model at a time, trying to access a relationship on multiple coordinations for ex will not work unless you loop through them. I don't think this is directly possible with has_many relationships, but I'm sure you could write a simple loop to get around this, except it would have to be in your controller as this sort of logic isn't good to be in the view. I'm sure you could even write it from within your model, I might try and write something up for you when I have a free moment as I'm at work right now.

Comment: Hey no worries, I was just wondering if is exists a direct way to do this, If I remember well, Django do this in this way ... or maybe not. Any way, thanks for the help and the tips.

Comment: I gave it a go anyway, check my edited answer. It isn't tested but there's a chance it could work, there should be a way to do this directly really as you said, I'm sure it will be implemented at some point!

Comment: I was trying this approach. I'll test it but this should work. My concerns is that if this way it queries for every model or do something else. But that's another discussion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Either way, the only logically possible way of getting all assets for each department this way is by querying all of those models. It isn't otherwise possible, but I suppose that's what caching was built for. But yes, the main thing is that you have a solution :)

Comment: This is weird, but I get now Method [assets] is not defined on the Query class. Checked the Site assets method and doesn't seems to have anything wrong. Laravel is nice but I think it lacks of a better Doc.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, but I suppose it's as far as it gets. It seems the assets() relationship method is incorrectly named, but it doesn't look like it is. And yes, Laravel is a good framework but there are still features and explanations to be implemented, although it is still a baby! There is quite a responsive forum too who are always available to help. I am using it a lot right now and finding it works perfectly for everything I need, so far!

Comment: I don't get it, changed the name to the relationship and it doesnt work. But I don't know why this trace: "Laravel\Database\Query->__call('as_assets', Array)" the query  is triggering the error, not the model. -